# how to match the case sensitive characters in elements

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to match the two or more case-sensitive characters in element of **familName** in **author** element. If found the ERROR message should be shown otherwise the **familyName** content will shown. The below code is not viewed in browser. Please check. I have used the xsl version is 2.0.

**XML CODE**

```
<author><familyName>CH</familyName> <givenNames>JC</givenNames></author>
```

**XSLT CODE**

```
<xsl:for-each select="author">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="matches(familyName,'([A-Z]){{1,}}')"><xsl:text>ERROR</xsl:text></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="familyName"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You mean that two or more uppercase characters?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. You can write a specific template for showing error:

```
<xsl:template match="familyName[matches(.,'^[A-Z][A-Z]+')]">
    <xsl:text>ERROR</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```